# Delegate in Dispatcher.BeginInvoke refers to Base class virtual method

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I am stuck in a situation like below.

I am trying to call derived class overridden function from a Dispatcher.BeginInvoke, using delegate. But the delegate always calls the base class virtual method instead of derived class overridden method.

How to solve the issue?

Below is my pseudo code:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass() { }
    public virtual void DoWork(int i)
    {
        //do nothing

    }
}

class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClass() { }
    public override void DoWork(int i)
    {
        MessageBox.Show((i + 2).ToString());
    }
}
public delegate void delDoWork(int i);
class SomeClass
{
   private void SomeMethod()
   {
        oDerived = new DerivedClass();

        ThreadStart ts = delegate
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
            new delDoWork(oDerived.DoWork), i);
        };
        new Thread(ts).Start();
  }
}
```

Comment: In `new DoWork(...)` Is `DoWork` a delegate type?

Comment: Just updated.. please see again.

Comment: Should BeginInvoke be `(method, priority, args)`? To be clear, you are using System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher, right?

Comment: Yes...it is System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher and it is using below type BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority, Delegate, Object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it isn't calling anything at all.
Because your BaseClass.DoWork is empty, you may have been mislead to think it was calling that one.

Consider this code:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public virtual void DoWork(int i)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fruit " + i);
    }
}

public class Orange : Fruit
{
    public override void DoWork(int i)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Orange " + i);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    delegate void DoWork(int i);

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ThreadStart ts = delegate
        {
            var obj = new Orange();
            int i = 0;
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new DoWork(obj.DoWork), DispatcherPriority.Normal, i);
        };
        new Thread(ts).Start();
    }
}
```

When I run this and trigger the event, *nothing* happens.
Buthen I replace the BeginInvoke line with this:

```
Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new DoWork(obj.DoWork), DispatcherPriority.Normal, i).Wait();
```

Then it works as expected (prints "Orange 0")

For some reason it only executes the code when `Wait` is used (or if `BeginInvoke` is replaced by `Invoke`).